# Is $\mathbf{PGL}_2(k)$ a characteristic subgroup of $\mathbf{P\Gamma L}_2(k)$, $k$ a division ring?

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, projective-geometry

Let $k$ be a division ring, and consider the projective semilinear group $\mathbf{P\Gamma L}_2(k) =: L$.

We know that $L$ has a naturally defined normal subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbf{PGL}_2(k)$ (if we introduce $\mathbf{P\Gamma L}_2(k)$ as $\mathbf{PGL}_2(k) \rtimes \mathrm{Aut}(k)$).

Is it also a *characteristic subgroup* of $L$ ?

(If I am not mistaken, this is the case if $k$ is a finite field, possibly up to some small counter examples.)

Comment: It's true if $k$ is a field, because $S := {\rm PSL}(2,k)$ is simple, and then ${\rm Aut}(S) = {\rm P \Gamma L}(2,k)$ is complete, so all subgroups of ${\rm Aut}(S)$ that contain $S$ are characteristic. I don't know whether ${\rm PSL}(2,k)$ is necessarily simple when $k$ is a non-commutative division ring.

Comment: @DerekHolt: when $k$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2$ or $\mathbb{F}_3$ in the case when $n = 2$, $\mathbf{PSL}_n(k)$ indeed is simple if $k$ is a division ring. Is it known that $\mathbf{P\Gamma L}_n(k)$ is the automorphism group of $\mathbf{PSL}_n(k)$ ?

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what the answer is when $k$ is a non-commutative division ring.